# How do I write Web Api unit test which I should get info from the UserManager

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api, authorize-attribute

I've searched stackoverflow and googled four a couple of hours and still not found any solution for my "trivial" problem.

For example, I want to test this web api controller

```
public IHttpActionResult GetFavorites()
{
    var userApplication = UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
    var user = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Username == userApplication.UserName);
    if (user == null)
        return Unauthorized();

    return Ok(db.Favorites.Where(fav => fav.UserID == user.UserID));
}
```

I have tried to mock a context for my controller and also tried to change the Thread.CurrentPrincipal.

Some would be able to help me out on that, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post your current test code?

Comment: Have a look at http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/unit-testing-controllers-in-web-api

Answer (score 3):

The controller above is very hard to unit test in the current state. You have to mock the `UserManager`, `controller.User`, `db.Users` and `db.Favorites`. It leads to overloaded unit test which is hard to write and support. This is a perfect indication that controller does more than it should:

- Return an *Unauthorized* response if there is no user found
- Return a list of *Favorites* for the authorized user

How the users are stored and how to get the favorites are the tasks for the business logic. The simplified controller action may look like the following:

```
public IHttpActionResult GetFavorites()
{
  string userName = this.User.Identity.Name;
  if (!this.userService.IsAuthorized(userName))
  {
    return this.Unauthorized();
  }
  var favs = this.userService.GetFavorites(userName);
  return Ok(favs);
}
```

The unit test that checks if the action returns unauthorized access:

```
  // arrange
  var userService = Substitute.For<IUserService>();
  var controller = new FavoritesController(userService);

  // act
  var result = controller.GetFavorites();

  // assert
  result.Should().BeOfType<UnauthorizedResult>();
```

The test which checks if the action returns the user's favorites:

```
  // arrange
  var userService = Substitute.For<IUserService>();
  var controller = new FavoritesController(userService);

  var favorites = new[] { "fav1", "fav2" };
  userService.IsAuthorized("John").Returns(true);
  userService.GetFavorites("John").Returns(favorites);

  controller.User = Substitute.For<IPrincipal>();
  controller.User.Identity.Name.Returns("John");

  // act
  var result = controller.GetFavorites();

  // assert
  result.Should().BeOfType<OkNegotiatedContentResult<string[]>>();
  ((OkNegotiatedContentResult<string[]>)result).Content.Should().BeSameAs(favorites);
```

And finally, the `IUserService` interface:

```
public interface IUserService
{
  bool IsAuthorized(string userName);

  string[] GetFavorites(string userName);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. As you said, I will change the business logic in order to to make it easier to test/deploy/maintain.

Answer (score 2):

You need to mock out everything that you're not really testing.

The first one on that list is `UserManager.FindById()` and you'll note that you can't mock that directly since it's an extension method. You can mock `IUserStor0`e though and use a real `UserManager` against it.

---

The same applies to `IIdentity.GetUserId` but we can mock around that too. See below

**Edit**

It's probably worth pointing out that you're trying to find your `IdentityUser` using the Id, then querying your other user table using it's `UserName`. You could have just used `User.Identity.Name` from the get go and saved yourself some of the below effort.

---

Mocking `DbSet` is a little more complicated but doable. You'll need to declare your `DbContext` using virtual `IDbSet` instead of regular `DbSet`

e.g.

```
public class MyContext {
    public virtual IDbSet<User> Users { get; set;}
    public virtual IDbSet<Favourite> Favourites { get; set; }
}
```

In order to mock these so that your queries work in your controller method we need a helper function

```
    public Mock<IDbSet<T>> CreateMockDbSet<T>(IQueryable<T> data) where T:     
      class
    {
        var dbSet = new Mock<IDbSet<T>>();
        dbSet.Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(data.Provider);
        dbSet.Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(data.Expression);
        dbSet.Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(data.ElementType);
        dbSet.Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(data.GetEnumerator());

        return dbSet;
    }
```

This lets us create a Mock `IDbSet<T>` and preload it with our test data.

(using NUnit and Moq - but use whatever you want)

```
[Test]
public void TestGetFavourites()
{
    var user = new ApplicationUser {Id = 1, UserName = "Test"};

    //Mock UserStore so our UserManager calls work
    var userStore = new Mock<IQueryableUserStore<ApplicationUser, string>>();
    userStore.Setup(m => m.FindByIdAsync(It.IsAny<int>)))
      .Returns(Task.FromResult(user));

    var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser, int>(userStore.Object);

    // Mock our db context

    var users = new List<User>
    {
        new Api.User()
        {
            UserId = 1,
            UserName = "Test"
        }
    }.AsQueryable();

    var favourites = new List<Favourite>
    {
        new Favourite
        {
            UserId = 1
        }
    }.AsQueryable();

    var dbUsers = CreateMockDbSet(users);
    var dbFavourites = CreateMockDbSet(favourites);

    var dbContext = new Mock<MyContext>();
    dbContext.Setup(m => m.Favourites).Returns(dbFavourites.Object);
    dbContext.Setup(m => m.Users).Returns(dbUsers.Object);

    //You didn't specify how your controller got it's UserManager 
    // and db instances so I'm assuming constructor injection 
    var controller = new TestController(userManager, dbContext.Object);

    // Allows User.Identity.GetUserId() to work.
    var identity = new ClaimsIdentity();
    identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "1"));
    controller.User = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);


    // Run our tests

    var response = controller.GetFavourites();

    Assert.IsInstanceOf<OkNegotiatedContentResult<
      IQueryable<Favourite>>>(response);
    var responseObject = (OkNegotiatedContentResult<
      IQueryable<Favourite>>) response;
    Assert.That(responseObject.Content.Count(), Is.EqualTo(1));(response);
}
```

Now. There's an awful lot of code we need to mock there to test one method. This is generally a sign that you need to abstract some of your logic away. A good start would be to implement a `UserRepository` and a `FavouritesRepository` that handles getting users and getting favourites respectively.

You can then test them separately and mock out both completely when testing this method.

Comment: As of EF6, you can set your DbSet to virtual.

Answer (score 0):

You can inject a service in your controller

```
public interface ICurrentUserService
{
    int? GetUserId();
}
```

and implement it to work in your app

```
public HttpUserService : ICurrentUserService
{
    public int? GetUserId()
    {
        return User.Identity.GetUserId();
    }
}
```

and from you controller do this

```
var userApplication = UserManager.FindById(_myService.GetUserId());
```

and then mock it in your test

```
public HardCodedUserService : ICurrentUserService
{
    public int? GetUserId()
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

or in any other way you mock your services.